linear optimization using lagrange multipliers
there are two sources of energy (say Wind and Solar) and two custumers (say X and Y). I want to calculate the minimum cost distribution of the flow knowing that both costumers must meet their demand (or $x_s + x_w = D_x$ and $y_s + y_w = D_y$ ) and both sources cannot surpass a given capacity (or $x_s + y_s \leq S_{max}$ and $x_w + y_w \leq W_{max}$ ).
I define the cost as: $$ f = c_s * (x_s + y_s) + c_w * (x_w + y_w) $$
(note $c_s$ and $c_w$ are two constants of the problem, namely the cost of wind/solar for kWh) but I cannot find the solution of the problem when defined in the Lagrange framework. Reading other posts, probably there is some hypothesis which is not satisfied. In practice, this is the Lagrangian:
$$ L = f - \lambda_1 * g - \lambda_2 * h - \lambda_3 * l - \lambda_4 * m $$
with:

\begin{align}
(i) g &= x_s + x_w - D_x \\
(ii) h &= y_s + y_w - D_y\\
(iii) l &= x_s + y_s - S_{max}\\
(iv) m &= x_w + y_w - W_{max}\\
\end{align}

(iii and iv should be inequalities). When I derive $L$ with respect ({$x_s$, $y_s$, $x_w$, $y_w$}) I end up with a system of 4 redundant equations, thus I am not able to find a stationary point. In fact, If I modify slightly one of the conditions, I obtain a non-trivial result, while even if I modify the cost function (with e.g. a quadratic term), I find no solution. I imagine that the constraint as they are are parallel solutions and never crossing.
Is there a way to formulate my problem differently (while keeping the physical interpretation), or to solve it in another analytical way?
Also, I double checked from the numerical point of view and scipy works perfectly, while a formal solution with sympy (with and without KKT conditions) give no solution.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Objective function
def objective(x):
    xs, xw, ys, yw = x
    return a * (xs + ys) + b * (xw + yw)

# Constraints
constraints = [
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] + x[1] - Dx},  # xs + xw = Dx
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: S - (x[0] + x[2])},  # xs + ys <= S
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[2] + x[3] - Dy},  # ys + yw = Dy
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: W - (x[1] + x[3])}  # xw + yw <= W
]

# Coefficients
a = 0.3
b = 0.1
Dx = 13
S = 20
Dy = 10
W = 15

# Initial guesses
x0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])

# Solve
solution = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=constraints)
print(solution)

xs, ys, xw, yw = symbols('xs ys xw yw', real=True, nonnegative=True)
a, b, Dx, S, Dy, W = symbols('a b Dx S Dy W', real=True)
l1, l2, l3, l4 = symbols('l1 l2 l3 l4', real=True)

# Cost function
f = a*(xs + ys) + b*(xw + yw)

# Constraints
g = xs + xw - Dx
h = xs + ys - S
l = ys + yw - Dy
m = xw + yw - W

# Define Lagrangian
L = f - l1*g - l2*h - l3*l - l4*m

# Compute the derivative of the Lagrange function
dL_dxs = diff(L, xs)
dL_dxw = diff(L, xw)
dL_dys = diff(L, ys)
dL_dyw = diff(L, yw)

dL_dl1 = diff(L, l1)
dL_dl2 = diff(L, l2)
dL_dl3 = diff(L, l3)
dL_dl4 = diff(L, l4)

# Solve the KKT conditions
solution = solve([
    dL_dxs, dL_dxw, dL_dys, dL_dyw,
    dL_dl1, dL_dl2, dL_dl3, dL_dl4,
    g, h, l, m],             
    (xs, xw, ys, yw, l1, l2, l3, l4))

solution


Thank you

Lol :) hope I didn't initiate a Greek tragedy

From the equality restrictions we have
$$
\cases{
x_s = D_x-x_w\\
y_s = D_y-y_w
}
$$
and after substitution we have the reduced problem
$$
\min_{x_w,y_w}c_s(D_x+D_y)+(c_w-c_s)(x_w+y_w)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \cases{x_w+y_w \le W_{max}\\ x_w+y_w \ge D_x+D_y -S_{max}}
$$
and making  $\eta = x_w+y_w$ the problem reads
$$
\min_{\eta}c_s(D_x+D_y)+(c_w-c_s)\eta\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \cases{\eta \le W_{max}\\ \eta \ge D_x+D_y -S_{max}}
$$
The source of problems is that the formulation has an unknown in excess...
With the furnished parameter values we get a minimum value of $3.9$ for $\eta = 15$.

The method of Lagrange multipliers only works for equality constrained optimization problems whereas you have inequality constraints.
You can transform your inequalities into equalities by introducing slack variables $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and noting
$$x_s + x_w \leq D_x \iff x_s + x_w + \alpha^2 = D_x$$
$$y_s + y_w \leq D_y \iff y_s + y_w + \beta^2 = D_y$$
Your Lagrangian is then
$$\mathcal{L} = f + \lambda_1 \left( x_s + x_w + \alpha^2 - D_x \right) + \lambda_2 \left( y_s + y_w + \beta^2 - D_y \right) + \lambda_3 \left( x_s + y_s - S_{\max} \right) + \lambda_4 \left( x_w + y_w - W_{\max} \right)$$
Setting gradients to zero we have
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_s} = c_s + \lambda_1 + \lambda_3 = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_w} = c_w + \lambda_1 + \lambda_4 = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y_s} = c_s + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y_w} = c_w + \lambda_2 + \lambda_4 = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda_1} = x_s + x_w + \alpha^2 - D_x = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda_2} = y_s + y_w + \beta^2 - D_y = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda_3} = x_s + y_s - S_{\max} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda_4} = x_w + y_w - W_{\max} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \alpha} = 2 \lambda_1 \alpha = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \beta} = 2 \lambda_2 \beta = 0$$
where the last two inequalities are equivalent to complementary slackness. I'll leave it to you to solve this system of 10 equations in 10 unknowns; I've got finals I'm supposed to be studying for :)

A further hint is that you should solve it on a case-by-case basis. Note that $\lambda_1$ and $\alpha$ cannot both be non-zero, and the same for $\lambda_2$ and $\beta$, so consider the different cases separately.
